# My iOS app crashes without error when profiling on iOS 9 but not on iOS 8. Why?

Tags: ios, out-of-memory, low-memory

If I 'Profile' my relatively large app on Xcode 7.2 (7C68) with the `Timer Profiler`, my app exits after about 7 seconds. I have no other apps running (that might be contending for system memory resources, say).

Otherwise, if I use Cmd+R, the app runs well past 7 seconds — it runs as normal.

Is profiling support for iOS 9 broken somehow?  I'm trying to resolve an issue with memory pressure.

Comment: seems a memory issue. Please check object allocation. Also use 'Profile' for memory allocation & leak.

Answer (score 0):

Have comment all NSLog statements in your project.
 Fix it by disabling the NSLog statements (profiling on release and not on debug) will solve the issue .